# How did I break the auto resize feature of the Automatic Image Montage jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image-gallery

Sorry in advance if this is confusing. I've incorporated the [Automatic Image Montage jQuery](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/30/automatic-image-montage/) plugin for a page I'm working on and seem to have broken the feature that automatically resizes images upon a window resize event. Everything else about the plugin is working as it should. What am I doing wrong?

I'm pretty inexperienced with jQuery and Javascript, but have only modified a few of the max/min image size options in the plugin's js file. The internal reference in the js file that seems related to this problem is 'smartresize.' If you don't want to download the demo from the link above I've included a de-minified version of the js file below. First, my relevant css and html are as follows:

**CSS**

```
/*=========================automontage==============================*/
.am-container {
margin-top:75px;
}
.am-wrapper{
float:left;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
}
.am-wrapper img{
position:absolute;
outline:none;
}
/*=========================automontage==============================*/
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="am-container" id="am-container">
   <a href="#="asdf"><img src="img/265_s.jpg"></img></a>
   <a href="#" title="asdf"><img src="img/mont1_cloud_s.jpg"></img></a>
   <a href="#" title="asdf"><img src="img/san_diego_street.jpg"></img></a>
   <a href="#" title="asdf"><img src="img/IMG_8576_s.jpg"></img></a>
   <a href="#" title="asdf"><img src="img/IMG_9827_1_s.jpg"></img></a>
   <a href="#" title="asdf"><img src="img/IMG_0999_s.jpg"></img></a>
   <a href="#" title="asdf"><img src="img/Lake_pano_11.jpg"></img></a>
   <a href="#" title="asdf"><img src="img/IMG_8967_s.jpg"></img></a>
   <a href="#" title="asdf"><img src="img/IMG_1346_s.jpg"></img></a>
   <a href="#" title="asdf"><img src="img/IMG_2450.jpg"></img></a>
</div>
```

**In HTML script**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.montage.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
                /*automontage*/                 
                    $(function() {

                        var $container  = $('#am-container'),
                            $imgs       = $container.find('img').hide(),
                            totalImgs   = $imgs.length,
                            cnt         = 0;

                        $imgs.each(function(i) {
                            var $img    = $(this);
                            $('<img/>').load(function() {
                                ++cnt;
                                if( cnt === totalImgs ) {
                                    $imgs.show();
                                    $container.montage({
                                        fillLastRow             : true,
                                        alternateHeight         : true,
                                        alternateHeightRange    : {
                                            min : 150,
                                            max : 350
                                        }
                                    });


                                    }
                            }).attr('src',$img.attr('src'));
                        }); 

                    });                 

            </script>
```

**jQuery Plugin File Code (de-minified)**

```js
/**
 * jQuery Montage plugin
 * http://www.codrops.com/
 *
 * Copyright 2011, Pedro Botelho
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 * Date: Tue Aug 30 2011
 */
(function( window, $, undefined ) {
 
 /*
 * Array.max, Array.min 
 * @John Resig
 * http://ejohn.org/blog/fast-javascript-maxmin/
 */
 
 // function to get the Max value in array
    Array.max      = function( array ){
        return Math.max.apply( Math, array );
    };

    // function to get the Min value in array
    Array.min      = function( array ){
       return Math.min.apply( Math, array );
    };
 
 /*
 * smartresize: debounced resize event for jQuery
 *
 * latest version and complete README available on Github:
 * https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.smartresize.js
 *
 * Copyright 2011 @louis_remi
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 */

 var $event = $.event, resizeTimeout;

 $event.special.smartresize  = {
  setup: function() {
   $(this).bind( "resize", $event.special.smartresize.handler );
  },
  teardown: function() {
   $(this).unbind( "resize", $event.special.smartresize.handler );
  },
  handler: function( event, execAsap ) {
   // Save the context
   var context = this,
    args  = arguments;

   // set correct event type
   event.type = "smartresize";

   if ( resizeTimeout ) { clearTimeout( resizeTimeout ); }
   resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery.event.handle.apply( context, args );
   }, execAsap === "execAsap"? 0 : 50 );
  }
 };

 $.fn.smartresize    = function( fn ) {
  return fn ? this.bind( "smartresize", fn ) : this.trigger( "smartresize", ["execAsap"] );
 };
 
 // ======================= imagesLoaded Plugin ===============================
 // https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

 // $('#my-container').imagesLoaded(myFunction)
 // execute a callback when all images have loaded.
 // needed because .load() doesn't work on cached images

 // callback function gets image collection as argument
 //  `this` is the container

 // original: mit license. paul irish. 2010.
 // contributors: Oren Solomianik, David DeSandro, Yiannis Chatzikonstantinou

 $.fn.imagesLoaded    = function( callback ) {
  var $images = this.find('img'),
   len  = $images.length,
   _this  = this,
   blank  = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==';

  function triggerCallback() {
   callback.call( _this, $images );
  }

  function imgLoaded() {
   if ( --len <= 0 && this.src !== blank ){
    setTimeout( triggerCallback );
    $images.unbind( 'load error', imgLoaded );
   }
  }

  if ( !len ) {
      triggerCallback();
  }

  $images.bind( 'load error',  imgLoaded ).each( function() {
      // cached images don't fire load sometimes, so we reset src.
      if (this.complete || this.complete === undefined){
    var src = this.src;
    // webkit hack from http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/eee6ab7b2da50e1f
    // data uri bypasses webkit log warning (thx doug jones)
    this.src = blank;
    this.src = src;
      }
  });

  return this;
 }; 
 
 $.Montage      = function( options, element ) {
  this.element  = $( element ).show();
  this.cache  = {};
  this.heights = new Array();
  this._create( options );
 };
 
 $.Montage.defaults    = {
  liquid     : true, // if you use percentages (or no width at all) for the container's width, then set this to true
          // this will set the body's overflow-y to scroll ( fix for the scrollbar's width problem ) 
  margin     : 1, // space between images.
  minw     : 70, // the minimum width that a picture should have.
  minh     : 20, // the minimum height that a picture should have.
  maxh     : 250, // the maximum height that a picture should have.
  alternateHeight   : false,// alternate the height value for every row. If true this has priority over defaults.fixedHeight.
  alternateHeightRange : {  // the height will be a random value between min and max.
   min : 100,
   max : 300
  },
  fixedHeight    : null, // if the value is set this has priority over defaults.minsize. All images will have this height.
  minsize     : false,// minw,minh are irrelevant. Chosen height is the minimum one available.
  fillLastRow    : false // if true, there will be no gaps in the container. The last image will fill any white space available
    };
 
 $.Montage.prototype   = {
  _getImageWidth  : function( $img, h ) {
   var i_w = $img.width(), i_h = $img.height(), r_i = i_h / i_w;
   return Math.ceil( h / r_i );
  },
  _getImageHeight  : function( $img, w ) {
   var i_w = $img.width(), i_h = $img.height(), r_i = i_h / i_w;
   return Math.ceil( r_i * w );
  },
  _chooseHeight  : function() {
   // get the minimum height
   if( this.options.minsize ) {
    return Array.min( this.heights );
   }
   // otherwise get the most repeated heights. From those choose the minimum.
   var result  = {}, 
    max  = 0, 
    res, val, min;
    
   for( var i = 0, total = this.heights.length; i < total; ++i ) {
    var val = this.heights[i], inc = ( result[val] || 0 ) + 1;
    
    if( val < this.options.minh || val > this.options.maxh ) continue;
    
    result[val] = inc;
    
    if( inc >= max ) { 
     max = inc; res = val;
    }
   }
   for (var i in result) {
    if (result[i] === max) {
     val = i;
     min = min || val;
     
     if(min < this.options.minh)
      min = null;
     else if (min > val)
      min = val;
     if(min === null) 
      min = val;
    }
   }
   if(min === undefined) min = this.heights[0];
   
   res = min;
   
   return res;
  },
  _stretchImage  : function( $img ) {
   var prevWrapper_w = $img.parent().width(),
    new_w    = prevWrapper_w + this.cache.space_w_left,
    crop    = {
     x  : new_w,
     y : this.theHeight
    };
   
   var new_image_w  = $img.width() + this.cache.space_w_left,
    new_image_h  = this._getImageHeight( $img, new_image_w );
   
   this._cropImage( $img, new_image_w, new_image_h, crop );
   this.cache.space_w_left = this.cache.container_w;
   // if this.options.alternateHeight is true, change row / change height
   if( this.options.alternateHeight) 
    this.theHeight   = Math.floor( Math.random()*( this.options.alternateHeightRange.max - this.options.alternateHeightRange.min + 1 ) + this.options.alternateHeightRange.min );  
  },
  _updatePrevImage : function( $nextimg ) {
   var $prevImage   = this.element.find('img.montage:last');
   
   this._stretchImage( $prevImage );
   
   this._insertImage( $nextimg );
  },
  _insertImage  : function( $img ) {
   // width the image should have with height = this.theHeight.
   var new_w = this._getImageWidth( $img, this.theHeight );
   
   // use the minimum height available if this.options.minsize = true.
   if( this.options.minsize && !this.options.alternateHeight ) {
    if( this.cache.space_w_left <= this.options.margin * 2 ) {
     this._updatePrevImage( $img );
    }
    else {
     if( new_w > this.cache.space_w_left ) {
      var crop = { x : this.cache.space_w_left, y : this.theHeight };
      this._cropImage( $img, new_w, this.theHeight, crop );
      this.cache.space_w_left = this.cache.container_w;
      $img.addClass('montage');
     } 
     else {
      var crop = { x  : new_w, y : this.theHeight };
      this._cropImage( $img, new_w, this.theHeight, crop );
      this.cache.space_w_left -= new_w;
      $img.addClass('montage');
     }
    } 
   }
   else {
    // the width is lower than the minimum width allowed.
    if( new_w < this.options.minw ) {
     // the minimum width allowed is higher than the space left to fill the row.
     // need to resize the previous (last) item in that row.
     if( this.options.minw > this.cache.space_w_left ) {
      this._updatePrevImage( $img );
     } 
     else {
      var new_w = this.options.minw, new_h = this._getImageHeight( $img, new_w ), crop = { x : new_w, y : this.theHeight };
      this._cropImage( $img, new_w, new_h, crop );
      this.cache.space_w_left -= new_w;
      $img.addClass('montage');
     }
    }
    else {
     // the new width is higher than the space left but the space left is lower than the minimum width allowed.
     // need to resize the previous (last) item in that row.
     if( new_w > this.cache.space_w_left && this.cache.space_w_left < this.options.minw ) {
      this._updatePrevImage( $img );
     } 
     else if( new_w > this.cache.space_w_left && this.cache.space_w_left >= this.options.minw ) {
      var crop = {x : this.cache.space_w_left, y : this.theHeight};
      this._cropImage( $img, new_w, this.theHeight, crop );
      this.cache.space_w_left = this.cache.container_w;
      // if this.options.alternateHeight is true, change row / change height
      if( this.options.alternateHeight)
       this.theHeight = Math.floor( Math.random()*( this.options.alternateHeightRange.max - this.options.alternateHeightRange.min + 1 ) + this.options.alternateHeightRange.min );
      $img.addClass('montage');
     } 
     else {
      var crop = { x : new_w, y : this.theHeight};
      this._cropImage( $img, new_w, this.theHeight, crop );
      this.cache.space_w_left -= new_w;
      $img.addClass('montage');
     } 
    }
   }
  },
  _cropImage   : function( $img, w, h, cropParam ) {
   // margin value
   var dec = this.options.margin * 2;
   
   var $wrapper = $img.parent('a');
   
   // resize the image
   this._resizeImage( $img, w, h );
   
   // adjust the top / left values to slice the image without loosing the its ratio
   $img.css({
    left : - ( w - cropParam.x ) / 2 + 'px',
    top  : - ( h - cropParam.y ) / 2 + 'px'
   }); 
   
   // wrap the image in a <a> element
   $wrapper.addClass('am-wrapper').css({
    width : cropParam.x - dec + 'px',
    height : cropParam.y + 'px',
    margin  : this.options.margin
   });
  },
  _resizeImage  : function( $img, w, h ) {
   $img.css( { width : w + 'px', height : h + 'px' } );
  },
  _reload    : function() {
   // container's width
   var new_el_w = this.element.width();
   
   // if different, something changed...
   if( new_el_w !== this.cache.container_w ) {
    this.element.hide();
    this.cache.container_w  = new_el_w;
    this.cache.space_w_left  = new_el_w;
    var instance     = this;
    instance.$imgs.removeClass('montage').each( function(i) {
     instance._insertImage( $(this) );
    });
    if( instance.options.fillLastRow && instance.cache.space_w_left !== instance.cache.container_w ) {
     instance._stretchImage( instance.$imgs.eq( instance.totalImages - 1 ) );
    } 
    instance.element.show();
   }
  },
  _create    : function( options ) {
   this.options  = $.extend( true, {}, $.Montage.defaults, options );
   
   var instance   = this,
    el_w    = instance.element.width();
   
   instance.$imgs  = instance.element.find('img');
   instance.totalImages= instance.$imgs.length;
   
   // solve the scrollbar width problem.
   if( instance.options.liquid )
    $('html').css( 'overflow-y', 'scroll' );
   
   // save the heights of all images.
   if( !instance.options.fixedHeight ) {
    instance.$imgs.each( function(i) {
     var $img = $(this), img_w = $img.width();
     
     // if images have width > instance.options.minw then "resize" image.
     if( img_w < instance.options.minw && !instance.options.minsize ) {
      var new_h = instance._getImageHeight( $img, instance.options.minw );
      instance.heights.push( new_h );
     }
     else {
      instance.heights.push( $img.height() );
     } 
    });
   }
   
   // calculate which height to use for each image.
   instance.theHeight   = ( !instance.options.fixedHeight && !instance.options.alternateHeight ) ? instance._chooseHeight() : instance.options.fixedHeight;
   
   if( instance.options.alternateHeight )
    instance.theHeight  = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( instance.options.alternateHeightRange.max - instance.options.alternateHeightRange.min + 1 ) + instance.options.alternateHeightRange.min );
    
   // save some values.
   instance.cache.container_w = el_w;
   // space left to fill the row.
   instance.cache.space_w_left = el_w;
   
   // wrap the images with the right sizes.
   instance.$imgs.each( function(i) {
    instance._insertImage( $(this) );
   });
   
   if( instance.options.fillLastRow && instance.cache.space_w_left !== instance.cache.container_w ) {
    instance._stretchImage( instance.$imgs.eq( instance.totalImages - 1 ) );
   }
   
   // window resize event : reload the container.
   $(window).bind('smartresize.montage', function() { 
    instance._reload();
   });
  },
  add     : function( $images, callback ) {
   // adds one or more images to the container
   var $images_stripped = $images.find('img');
   this.$imgs   = this.$imgs.add( $images_stripped );
   this.totalImages= this.$imgs.length;
   this._add( $images, callback );
  },
  _add    : function( $images, callback ) {
   var instance = this;
   $images.find('img').each( function(i) {
    instance._insertImage( $(this) );
   });
   
   if( instance.options.fillLastRow && instance.cache.space_w_left !== instance.cache.container_w )
    instance._stretchImage( instance.$imgs.eq( instance.totalImages - 1 ) );
   
   if ( callback ) callback.call( $images );
  },
  destroy    : function( callback ) {
   this._destroy( callback );
  },
  _destroy    : function( callback ) {
   this.$imgs.removeClass('montage').css({
    position : '',
    width  : '',
    height  : '',
    left  : '',
    top   : ''
   }).unwrap();
   
   if( this.options.liquid )
    $('html').css( 'overflow', '' );
   
   this.element.unbind('.montage').removeData('montage');

   $(window).unbind('.montage');
   
   if ( callback ) callback.call();
  },
  option    : function( key, value ) {
   // set options AFTER initialization:
   if ( $.isPlainObject( key ) ){
    this.options = $.extend( true, this.options, key );
   } 
  }
 };
 
 // taken from jquery.masonry
 //   https://github.com/desandro/masonry
 // helper function for logging errors
 // $.error breaks jQuery chaining
 var logError     = function( message ) {
  if ( this.console ) {
   console.error( message );
  }
 };
 
 // Structure taken from jquery.masonry
 //   https://github.com/desandro/masonry
 // =======================  Plugin bridge  ===============================
 // leverages data method to either create or return $.Montage constructor
 // A bit from jQuery UI
 //   https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js
 // A bit from jcarousel 
 //   https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/blob/master/lib/jquery.jcarousel.js

 $.fn.montage     = function( options ) {
  if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {
   // call method
   var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );

   this.each(function() {
    var instance = $.data( this, 'montage' );
    if ( !instance ) {
     logError( "cannot call methods on montage prior to initialization; " +
     "attempted to call method '" + options + "'" );
     return;
    }
    if ( !$.isFunction( instance[options] ) || options.charAt(0) === "_" ) {
     logError( "no such method '" + options + "' for montage instance" );
     return;
    }
    // apply method
    instance[ options ].apply( instance, args );
   });
  } 
  else {
   this.each(function() {
    var instance = $.data( this, 'montage' );
    if ( instance ) {
     // apply options & reload
     instance.option( options || {} );
     instance._reload();
    } 
    else {
     // initialize new instance
     $.data( this, 'montage', new $.Montage( options, this ) );
    }
   });
  }
  
  return this;
 };
 
})( window, jQuery );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Turns out that my jQuery plugin version, which I'd changed from 1.6.2 to 1.12.4, broke the plugin. I played with the plugin version until I found one that worked for the other plugins I'm using, too (magnific popup lightbox, automatic montage). Now all is working! 1.7.0 was what worked for all.